# Can someone tell me why this isn't creating a dm channel to the specified user when someone types !dm?

Tags: python, discord, bots

This will not work for some reason. I have no idea why it doesnt work

```
# adds an event
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  # so i dont have to say message.content a lot
  msg = message.content
  # if a message starts with !dm create a dm channel with the specified user
  if msg.content.startswith("!dm"):
    await create_dm('user')
```

Comment: Take a look at this and see if it helps.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61627733/discord-py-no-dm-sent-to-the-user

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a DM targeting a user.

```py
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    user = ctx.author
    await ctx.send(f"Hello, {user.mention}")
    dm = await user.create_dm()
    await dm.send('hello')
```

Also, as you can see in this code snippet here, I recommend setting up a command (as it looks like you're doing) with `@client.command` rather than targetting an `on_message` event.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# adds an event
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  # so i dont have to say message.content a lot
  msg = message.content
  # if a message starts with !dm create a dm channel with the specified user
  if msg.content.startswith("!dm"):
    await member.send (member "or whatever is defined")
```

Using member.send sends a message to a member creating a dm with the bot.